# Android - Cannot find a device in onScanResult callback after successful connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm scanning for BLE devices with my mobile. 
Whenever I get a callback of **onScanResult** I check if peripheral is iBeacon with specific minorId, if it is, I do device connection. Problem is that after successful connection **onScanResult** returns different devices around me, but none of them are the ones I just connected to. It's crucial for me to find connected devices in **onScanResult**. Is this normal behaviour? What could cause this? This happens when I connect to device - and only then.

Comment: Usually, after the something establishes the connection to device, it stops broadcasting because it is not available for another connection while occupied by some device. Check your beacon's documentation on if it is expected behavior or not.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Can you please write this as an answer with additional code on how to disconnect device by MAC address? If that works as intended, I'll mark your answer as solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `BluetoothGatt.close();` to disconnect from device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour according to the Bluetooth specification. For Bluetooth Low Energy devices, there are 6 predefined states:-

- Standby State
- Advertising State
- Scanning State
- Initiating State
- Connection State
- Synchronization State

In the spec, it is stated: "The Link Layer state machine allows only one state to be active at a time". This is demonstarated in the state machine below:-

[image]

This is why once you are connected to the advertising device, it switches state to "Connection" and remains in that state. If you had access to the device's code you could force it to advertise after connection, but not all devices support this feature.

For more information, check the [Bluetooth Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/) v5.1, Vol 6, Part B, Section 1: Link Layer States.